# Crontab not executing after code-signing in Mac

Tags: objective-c, cron, applescript, code-signing, osx-gatekeeper

I create cronJob in my mac application using apple script. It was working fine until codeSigning the application.

I had to code sign the application to keep away from gateKeepers. Each time i update the cron there was a gatekeeper popup. To remove gateKeepers i had to codeSign my application.

I used Developer ID Application certificate to codesign the application.

```
 NSDictionary *error1 = [NSDictionary new];
                        NSString *script1 =  @"tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \" crontab -l > mycron ; echo '* * * * * cd /Applications/PPFolder && ./CronCheck.sh >> /Applications/PPFolder/scriptlogs.log' >> mycron ; crontab mycron ; rm mycron ; exit;\" ";
                        NSAppleScript *appleScript1 = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:script1];
                        if ([appleScript1 executeAndReturnError:&error1]) {
                            NSLog(@"success!");
                        } else {
                            NSLog(@"failure!");
                        }
```

After CodeSigning. It only works on my machine and not on other machine. Is it due to code signing or does other mac requires extra permissions.

I tried CodeSigning the application. Post that it stoped working on other machines. I need to get the cron working on all machines any suggestions as to what is going wrong.

Comment: This looks like it could run into [Privacy/TCC restrictions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332673/what-and-how-does-macos-mojave-implement-to-restrict-applications-access-to-pers) at a number of points, and maybe file permissions as well. Your app will need the user to grant it Accessibility permission to control Terminal, which will require System Administration (I think it is) to change the crontab, the cron job itself will need write access to /Applications/PPFolder (things /Applications should not be user-writable) and maybe other things, ...

Comment: Hii @GordonDavisson Thanks you for the reply. i will check the link. 
I wanted to bring to your notice that the entire application with cron works perfectly in my mac machine. And it has been code signed from my ID. When i run the same application after building it in a another mac, Then the cron script does not execute.
When i remove the code sign. The application works fine on all machines. and also pops up a gatekeeper